# Add an ObservableCollection within a ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, observablecollection, windows-phone-8

I need to add a ObservableCollection ObservableCollection within another, is it possible?

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<WidgetCollectionItem>();

            foreach (XElement wid in document.Root.Elements("widget"))
            {
                WidgetCollectionItem item = new WidgetCollectionItem();

                item.nombreWidget = wid.Attribute("caption").Value;

                foreach (XElement service in wid.Elements("service"))
                {
                    item.nombreServicio = service.Attribute("caption").Value;
                    item.valor = service.Element("xvalue").Value;
                    item.color = service.Element("xcolor").Value;
                    item.alerta = service.Element("xalert") != null ? service.Element("xalert").Value : null;
                    Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
```

The problem is that each (item.nombreWidget) contains more than one (item.nombreServicio). And I need a ObservableCollection of services within an ObservableCollection of nombreWidget

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

```
new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<WidgetCollectionItem>>()
```

so you can do something like this:

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<WidgetCollectionItem>>();

foreach (XElement wid in document.Root.Elements("widget"))
{
    ObservableCollection<WidgetCollectionItem> services = new ObservableCollection<WidgetCollectionItem>();

    foreach (XElement service in wid.Elements("service"))
    {
        WidgetCollectionItem widget = new WidgetCollectionItem();
        widget.nombreWidget = wid.Attribute("caption").Value;
        widget.nombreServicio = service.Attribute("caption").Value;
        widget.valor = service.Element("xvalue").Value;
        widget.color = service.Element("xcolor").Value;
        widget.alerta = service.Element("xalert") != null ? service.Element("xalert").Value : null;
        services.Add(widget);
    }
    Items.Add(services)
}
```

Comment: You may want to consider adding a "Services" property to a WidgetCollectionItem of type ObservableCollection<ServiceCollectionItem>, and create a class that defines a service

Answer (score 0):

Good idea kindasimple, but still can not show what I want. I grab a xml data, and these want them displayed in a grid

The end result would be this:

nombreWidget1
    nombreServicio1

nombreWidget2
    nombreServicio2
    nombreServicio2
    nombreServicio2

If nombreWidget has only one service is fine, but if you have more than one nombreWidget nombreServicio, I can not show well on screen

I need the ObservableCollection

```
public class WidgetCollectionItem
{
    public string nombreWidget { get; set; }
}
```

Contains an ObservableCollection

```
public class WidgetServiciosCollectionItem 
{
        public string nombreServicio { get; set; }
        public string valor { get; set; }
        public string color { get; set; }
        public string alerta { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I got what I wanted to achieve, but still does not show me all the data in the grid:

Solution to earlier:

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<WidgetCollectionItem>();

            foreach (XElement wid in document.Root.Elements("widget"))
            {
                WidgetCollectionItem widget = new WidgetCollectionItem();
                widget.nombreWidget = wid.Attribute("caption").Value;

                foreach (XElement service in wid.Elements("service"))
                {
                    ServiciosWidgetCollectionItem ser = new ServiciosWidgetCollectionItem();
                    widget.ItemsSer = new ObservableCollection<ServiciosWidgetCollectionItem>();

                    ser.nombreServicio = service.Attribute("caption").Value;
                    ser.valor = service.Element("xvalue").Value;
                    ser.color = service.Element("xcolor").Value;
                    ser.alerta = service.Element("xalert") != null ? service.Element("xalert").Value : null;

                    widget.ItemsSer.Add(ser);
                }
                Items.Add(widget);
            }


public class WidgetCollectionItem
{
    public string nombreWidget { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ServiciosWidgetCollectionItem> ItemsSer { get; set; }
}


public class ServiciosWidgetCollectionItem
{
    public string nombreServicio { get; set; }
    public string valor { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string alerta { get; set; }
}
```

How do I go also in the data grid  ObservableCollection?